# What makes an app PowerPC based

Tags: java, macos, terminal, intel, powerpc

So I coded an app in Xcode in Objective-C, which packages a jar file so that it should run as if it were executed in Terminal. The Xcode app runs, but the packaged jar that the app creates gives an error

The app file structure is

Foo.app
-Contents
--Info.plist
--MacOS
---foo.jar
---launcher
--Resources

I also ran chmod a+x on the launcher to make it executable

The contents of the launcher are

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$( dirname "$0" )"
sudo java -Xmx1G -jar "foo.jar" -o true
```

When I try to run the packaged app it says that PowerPC apps are no longer supported.

Comment: Try adding what type of machine you are using, etc to garner better answers.

Comment: I'm running on an mid 2010 Mac pro

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code a few more times and noticed that when creating a launcher I used NSUnicodeStringEncoding instead of NSUTF8StringEncoding, which caused the app to not work.